# Get data from tables in one query

Tags: mysql, database

I have four tables in my database:

1. Coupon
2. Flyer
3. Deals
4. User

These tables have some data and a primary key.
A user can add a deal, coupon and flyer in adding to the cart. I want to know how to make an addition to the cart table where I can fetch all the coupons, deals and flyers in one query, according to the user ID.

Comment: And, what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mBVsJY8.png
But in this way i have to write three queries to get data

Answer (score 0):

Use each table's primary key as a foreign key in the AddToCart Table and get data using a join select query.

Comment: but i have to write three queries to get data i want to know if its possible to get all the data in one query?

Comment: Yes ofcourse You can join each query with Union All Keyword.

Comment: SELECT f.t_name as Flyer, c.name as coupan, u.name as Deal
FROM t_cart d
JOIN t_flyer f ON d.t_flyer_id = f.t_flyer_id
JOIN t_coupan c ON d.t_coupan_id = c.t_coupan_id
JOIN t_deal u ON d.t_deal_id = u.t_deal_id
where d.t_user_id = 1
I write a query like this but it is not giving me any result because only one column has the value in every entry and other two gets zero in their column so join is checking every column and try to match the values but other two does not match and its give me empty result

Comment: Your  Data and Requirement are not matching.Your query is not wrong.you should look over the data in your each table if you can show the table data i can tell you something more.

Comment: my add to cart table image i post above should i change my add to cart table? whenever user add item into add to cart only two column gets the data one is user_id and second coupon_id or deals_id or flyer_id and other two columns enters as zero so when i use join it checks all the column of one row and gets the result that's why i think my result is empty

Comment: You haven't managed you query. remove joins from last and arrange them one by one as per your need . I cant see you whole data to arrange this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to fetch the data and can use the primary key that is a foreign key for other table to make the join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` to get all the data in a single query, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM deals d
JOIN Flyer f ON d.t_flyer_id = f.id
JOIN Coupon c ON d.t_coupan_id = c.id
JOIN User u ON d.t_user_id ON u.id;
```

Comment: SELECT f.t_name as Flyer, c.name as coupan, u.name as Deal
FROM t_cart d
JOIN t_flyer f ON d.t_flyer_id = f.t_flyer_id
JOIN t_coupan c ON d.t_coupan_id = c.t_coupan_id
JOIN t_deal u ON d.t_deal_id = u.t_deal_id
where d.t_user_id = 1
But the result is empty

Comment: Try removing tables from `join` one by one and and see which condition results in no data.

Comment: when i use second join result always empty

Comment: So that means there is no coupon in for that id or id itself is not correct?

Comment: user only select  1 item to add in the cart so other column likes flyer_id and deals_id enters as zero and coupon_id gets the coupon id, when next time user enter anything in the cart new row create and same process repeat

Comment: should i change my add to cart table with one id which will contain flyer, deals ad coupon id and add one more column to like table name to identify which is belongs to which table?